# discord.py Embed answer with input

Tags: python

After include should be "term which got searched" i really have no clue how i can do this.

```
@bot.command()
async def search(ctx, file_name):
    search_result = ''
    from os import listdir
    for file in listdir('ArkFiles/Dinos'):
        if file_name in file.lower():
            search_result = search_result+'\n'+file
    if search_result == 'Search Results:':
        await ctx.reply('Error: Not matched with any file.')
    else:
         embed = discord.Embed(title="Here is a list of  files
 I found in the current Ark files that include "#term which got searched":")
         embed.add_field(name='** **', value= search_result, inline=False)
         await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to PEP 8

```py
Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments
 and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.
```

```py
from os import listdir

@bot.command()
async def search(ctx, *, file_name): # making it a keyword argument to take everything passed by the user
    search_result = ''
    for file in listdir('ArkFiles/Dinos'):
        if file_name in file.lower():
            search_result += '\nfile'
    if search_result == 'Search Results:':
        await ctx.reply('Error: Not matched with any file.')
    else:
         embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Here is a list of  files
 I found in the current Ark files that include {file_name}") # using the term which was searched
         embed.add_field(name='** **', value= search_result, inline=False)
         await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

You can use `f-strings` to format and include the term which was searched for, and yeah the rest of it is explained in the code comments

Comment: thx it is working now after slightly adjustments